# String to array or Array to string tips on formats, etc

Tags: php, regex, string

first of all thanks for taking your time!

I'm a junior Dev, working with PHP + mysql.

My issue:

I'm saving data from a form to my database. From this form, there's only need to save the contacts: Name, phone number, address. But, it would be nice to have a small reference to  the user answers.

Let's say for each question we've got a value betwee 1 and 4. Since there's no need to create a table just for it, because what's needed is just the personal contacts. I'm thinking of recording each question/answer, as a letter and its correspondent value.

Example (A2, B1, C5, D3, etc).

My question is:

Is there a format I could afterwards, handle easily ? Convert to array (string to array) in case the client change ideas, and ask this data, placed in table columns ? Just to prevent this situation!

Example,

From (A2, B1, C5 ) to array( "A" => "1", "B" => "1", "C" => "5" )

- - For now I guess, Regex is the answer, but it's allways hard to figure it out and I'm allways getting in troubles =)

Thanks!

Comment: store the data in a database.  It will be infinitely faster and more efficient that trying to parse a string. As well, if your boss later decides he wishes he could mine those responses, you'll be prepared. Believe me, if you collect data, someone at some point will want to do something you hadn't expected with it.  Better to store it properly to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not going to properly model this in a relational way, then just go with a serialized object.

PHP's [serialize()](https://www.php.net/serialize)/[unserialize(](https://www.php.net/unserialize)) (faster, more flexibile) or [json_encode()](https://www.php.net/json_encode)/[json_decode()](https://www.php.net/json_decode) (more human readable, more portable) will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [str_split()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) or [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).